# Python: read a file and replace it line by line with a certain condition

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a file like this below.

```
0       0       0 
0.00254 0.00047 0.00089
0.54230 0.87300 0.74500 
0       0       0
```

I want to modify this file. If a value is less than 0.05, then a value is to be 1. Otherwise, a value is to be 0.

After python script runs, the file should be like

```
1       1        1
1       1        1
0       0        0
1       1        1
```

Would you please help me?

Comment: Interesting problem, and very easy to solve. At which point are you stuck precisely?

Comment: Are you having trouble reading the file? Parsing the data? Writing to the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code

```
f_in=open("file_in.txt", "r")       #opens a file in the reading mode
in_lines=f_in.readlines()           #reads it line by line
out=[]
for line in in_lines:
    list_values=line.split()        #separate elements by the spaces, returning a list with the numbers as strings
    for i in range(len(list_values)):
        list_values[i]=eval(list_values[i])     #converts them to floats
#       print list_values[i],
        if list_values[i]<0.05:     #your condition
#           print ">>", 1
            list_values[i]=1
        else:
#           print ">>", 0
            list_values[i]=0
    out.append(list_values)         #stores the numbers in a list, where each list corresponds to a lines' content
f_in.close()                        #closes the file

f_out=open("file_out.txt", "w")     #opens a new file in the writing mode
for cur_list in out:
    for i in cur_list:
        f_out.write(str(i)+"\t")    #writes each number, plus a tab
    f_out.write("\n")               #writes a newline
f_out.close()                       #closes the file
```

Comment: This code is just very poorly written, I strongly advice to not use it! eval, no enumerate, no pep8, no context manager to open the file. While it _may_ serves (with a portion of luck) the purpose, I consider it really inappropriate as an answer here.

Answer (score 4):

OK, since you're new to StackOverflow (welcome!) I'll walk you through this. I'm assuming your file is called `test.txt`.

```
with open("test.txt") as infile, open("new.txt", "w") as outfile:
```

opens the files we need, our input file and a new output file. The `with` statement ensures that the files will be closed after the block is exited.

```
    for line in infile:
```

loops through the file line by line.

```
        values = [float(value) for value in line.split()]
```

Now this is more complicated. Every line contains space-separated values. These can be split into a list of strings using `line.split()`. But they are still strings, so they must be converted to `float`s first. All this is done with a list comprehension. The result is that, for example, after the second line has been processed this way, `values` is now the following list: `[0.00254, 0.00047, 0.00089]`.

```
        results = ["1" if value < 0.05 else "0" for value in values]
```

Now we're creating a new list called `results`. Each element corresponds to an element of `values`, and it's going to be a `"1"` if that `value < 0.05`, or a `"0"` if it isn't.

```
        outfile.write("      ".join(results))
```

converts the list of "integer strings" back to a string, separated by 7 spaces each.

```
        outfile.write("\n")
```

adds a newline. Done.

---

The two list comprehensions could be combined into one, if you don't mind the extra complexity:

```
        results = ["1" if float(value) < 0.05 else "0" for value in line.split()]
```

Answer (score 2):

if you can use libraries I'd suggest numpy :

```
import numpy as np
myarray = np.genfromtxt("my_path_to_text_file.txt")
my_shape = myarray.shape()
out_array = np.where(my_array < 0.05, 1, 0)
np.savetxt(out_array)
```

You can add formating as arguments to the savetxt function. The docstrings of the function are pretty self explanatory.

If you are stuck with pure python :

```
with open("my_path_to_text_file") as my_file:
    list_of_lines = my_file.readlines()
    list_of_lines = [[int( float(x) < 0.05) for x in line.split()] for line in list_of_lines]
```

then write that list to file as you see fit.

Answer (score 0):

The following code performs the replacements in-place: for that , the file is opened in `'rb+'` mode. It's absolutely mandatory to open it in binary mode `b`. The `+` in `'rb+'` means that it's possible to write and to read in the file. Note that the mode can be written `'r+b'` also.

But using `'rb+'` is awkward:

- if you read with `for line in f` , the file is read by chunks and several lines are kept in the buffer where they are really read one after the other, until another chunk of data is read and loaded in the buffer. That makes it harder to perform transformations, because one must follow the position of the file's pointer with the help of `tell()` and to move the pointer with `seek()` and in fact I've not completly  understood how it must done.
  .
  Happily, there's a solution with `replace()`, because , I don't know why, but I believe  the facts, when `readline()` reads a line, the file 's pointer doesn't go further on disk than the end of the line (that is to say it stops at the newline).
  Now it's easy to move and know positions of the file's pointer
- to make writing after reading, it's necessary to make `seek()` being executed , even if it should be to do `seek(0,1)`, meaning a move of 0 caracters from the actual position. That must change the state of the file's pointer, something like that.

Well, for your problem, the code is as follows:

```
import re
from os import fsync
from os.path import getsize

reg = re.compile('[\d.]+')

def ripl(m):
    g = m.group()
    return ('1' if float(g)<0.5 else '0').ljust(len(g))

path = ...........'

print 'length of file before : %d' % getsize(path)

with open('Copie de tixti.txt','rb+') as f:
    line = 'go'
    while line:
        line = f.readline()
        lg = len(line)
        f.seek(-lg,1)
        f.write(reg.sub(ripl,line))
        f.flush()
        fsync(f.fileno())

print 'length of file after : %d' % getsize(path)
```

`flush()` and `fsync()` must be executed to ensure that the instruction `f.write(reg.sub(ripl,line))` effectively writes at the moment it is ordred to.

Note that I've never managed a file encoded in unicode like. It's certainly still more dificult since every unicode character is encoded on several bytes (and in the case of UTF8 , variable number of bytes depending on the character)